# Installed modules not found, but show up in python interpreter config

Tags: module, pip

I tried to install EZGmail module for Python. When I check my interpreter settings, it shows it as installed in the PyCharm list. I then use this same interpreter for my project, but I get a module not found error when trying to import EZGmail. What should I check?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of the error as well since it'll be great to debug this ?

Comment: Sorry, here is the error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/OneDrive/cvo/Unsubscriber/unsubscriber.py", line 6, in <module>
    import EZGmail
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'EZGmail'

Comment: [Examples say](https://pypi.org/project/EZGmail/) it's `import ezgmail`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to import the module in a different casing than it's mentioned on the document.

You're trying to do:

```
import EZGmail
```

while the [Quickstart document](https://github.com/asweigart/ezgmail#quickstart-guide) says:

```
import ezgmail
```

Comment: Wow, I just assumed when you import the name should match the module's casing as it's listed. Thanks for catching this!

Comment: It's the case in general, but there's no rule as such :) . Also, you also might be surprised with a few cases where the import differs completely from the package name.